# Suspend two fingers back

Tags: keyboard, trackpad, multi-touch

Is it possible to disable this feature temporary?
I like to use it but it is so annoying when you are using spreadsheet or something with scrollable page.

The idea is next: when I press some button (let's say fn) + two finger swipe - it works as a regular scrolling, when I release fn button - default behaviour is activated again.

Is there any plugging/tweaks for that?

Comment: Maybe you can write a script that edits one of the various trackpad/accessibility plist  files using `default writes` command, then create an Apple shortcut (available in macOS Monterey) which triggers the execution of the script?

Answer (score 2):

In **System Preferences > Trackpad**, you can disable it, or set the gesture to use three fingers instead of two, which might make it less likely to activate when you're trying to scroll with two fingers.

[image: macOS Trackpad settings screenshot]
all options:

[image: options with "swipe with three fingers" selected]

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what i'm looking for.
I use both shortcuts quite often. I need something to suspend two fingers action temporary ideally while pressing some specific button.

There is no option to configure it from the system prefs. The only one way is some chrome extension or some mac extension/application.